# my registration form details are not getting in the database (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Whenever I try any new registration it creates the user but no information is fed into the database

database name is **chatbox**
and table name is **users**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('chatbox',$con);

    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];
    $pword2 = $_POST['password2'];

        if($pword != $pword2){

            echo "Passwords do not match. <br>";
                    }

        else {
        $checkexist = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$uname'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($checkexist)){
            echo "<center>";
            echo "Username already exists, Please select different username<br>";
            echo "</center>";
            }
        else {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users ('username','password') VALUES ('$uname','$pword')");    
            echo "<center>";
            echo "You have successfully registered. Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to go start chat<br>";
            echo "</center>";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `if (mysql_num_rows($checkexist) === 1){` Besides that your might want to read up on depecrated `mysql_*` functions, SQL injections and hasing.

Comment: Might I suggest you step over to mysqli? and ditch the deprecated mysql interface.

Comment: Just remove '(Single Quotes) from Database column name.Just place them as (username,password).

Answer (score 0):

There is a little unfamiliarity with your sql query. Try this.

```
INSERT INTO users (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('$uname','$pword')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should have a look at mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php it's the 'improved' version of mysql, and mysql is now deprecated as of php 5.5

Anyway, to help diagnose, you can use 'or die', to output a message if your script was unsuccessful.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("could not connect");
mysql_select_db('chatbox',$con) or die("could not select db");
```

if you're saving users' passwords in a database, you should definitely look into encrypting them, see: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php to begin with.

Janaka is right, in your insert statement, either use backticks for the fields `` or don't use any kind of quotes at all (username, password)